# Adding Colorbar and Contour Map to PyPlot surface imshow in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using code written by a former employee. In this code, the person performs a plot on Python using Qt. I'm trying to add a colorbar and contour maps, but to no avail. Here's part of the code that's relevant.

```
#IMPORTS
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

#SETUP
fig = Figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

#DRAWING
axes.clear()
axes.imshow(data_and_extents, interpolation='bilinear')
axes.autoscale(False)
canvas.draw()

#TODO: Add colorbar and contour maps with some values
```

I have tried `axes.colorbar()` to no avail. How do I add colorbars and contour maps to surface plots set up like this?

Thanks SOCommunity!

Comment: First error: First line should be `from matplotlib.figure import Figure`

Comment: Corrected. Still not working though :( I'll edit the code to avoid further confusion.

Comment: It should be `fig.colorbar` instead of `axes.colorbar`

Comment: Thanks! The issue now is this:

    colorbar() takes at least 1 argument (none given).

I'm wondering how to create a mappable object now per this guide -- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar

Comment: See this example: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html It should help you :) -> `cbar = fig.colorbar(axes)`

Comment: DING DING DING! Thank you! +1 for all your help folks.

Comment: I'll make it an answer for you to accept ok :)

Answer (score 1):

The first error is in the first line:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

is the correct one.
Next: Instead of `axes.colorbar` it's `fig.corbar`.
With your variable names you should be able to create a colorbar with:

```
cbar = fig.colorbar(axes)
```

See [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html) for more.